# Pyqt5: Hyperlink in table's cell

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm trying to insert a hyperlink into a table cell. How can I do this?

what i do:

```
self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('<a href="https://google.com">google</a>'))
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your code:

```
self.tableWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.OpenLink)

def OpenLink(self,item):
    if item.column() == 1:
        webbrowser.open('www.google.com')
```

you can change it based on your needs like that:
`item.text()` == the text in the cell, `item.row()` == row number and `item.column()` == column number.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this method, but I had an error with the condition "item.column() == 0:" because of which the method did not work. Now I decided to try without it and everything worked.

Comment: so you just removed the conditioning? (im asking so I can edit the answer :) )

Comment: By default, double-click cell editing was enabled. I disabled editing and added your condition. And it worked. Your answer is fine, you don't need to change it